# How do I access "absolute" object coordinates vs canvas GUI coordinates in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm a beginner in JS/D3.

I've got a plot of objects with "absolute" coordinates in some 2D space. Coordinates are like `[(2000,3000),(3500,4000),...]` etc. There are also "relative" coordinates from the GUI of the SVG container (i.e from top left of the browser window).

I don't understand how to get one type of coordinate versus the other.

For example, the following gives me the "relative" coordinates for the SVG GUI, which makes sense, since I'm calling it on the SVG itself.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .on("touchmove mousemove", moved)

function moved() {
    var point = d3.mouse(this);
    $("#lx").text(point[0].toFixed(0));
    $("#ly").text(point[1].toFixed(0));
    }
```

However, the below code gives me the "absolute" coordinates for the space my objects are plotted. It's calling the same `d3.mouse(this)` inside a drag function on my node:

```
var node = svg.selectAll('g') 
    .data(data) 
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.drag()
        .subject(function() { 
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
    })
    .on("drag", dragged))
    .attr("class", "node");

function dragged(d) {   
    coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
}
```

Somehow this is giving me the "absolute" coordinates I generally want and I don't understand why.

How can I get these "absolute" coordinates and not the GUI coordinates by calling a mousing event on the SVG object?

Also, would anyone kindly point me to literature explaining what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `coordinates = d3.mouse(svg.node())` gave me the code I wanted. Note the `.node()`, which is what D3 needed to get to the appropriate object (sorry for any terminology errors).